# Windows Server 2012 Printer Management

Tags: windows, networking, share, printer

I want to add a shared printer connected to a host IP (192.168.0.10,windows 7) , to a server (192.168.0.200,windows server 2012). When adding a printer using the Printer Management just the IP printers appears in the list, the shared printers don't. Meanwhile, using the Windows add printer from control panel displayed the shared printers and don't show the IP printers.

Notes:
1. Both hosts are located in the same sub-net.
2. The firewall disabled.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sharing the printer from the Windows 7 machine or are you sharing it from the Server 2012 machine? The latter would normally be how it is done.